# parsing "*" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing

Tags: c#, .net

fails when I try `Regex.Replace()` method.
how can i fix it?

```
Replace.Method (String, String, MatchEvaluator, RegexOptions)
```

I try code

```
<%# Regex.Replace( (Model.Text ?? "").ToString(), patternText, "<b>" + patternText + "</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline)%>
```

Comment: Er, *what* fails when you try Regex.Replace?

Comment: It occurs when I try not only *, + ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Did you try using only the string `"*"` as a regular expression? At least that's what causes your error here:

```
PS Home:\> "a" -match "*"
The '-match' operator failed: parsing "*" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing..
At line:1 char:11
+ "a" -match  <<<< "*"
```

The character `*` is special in regular expressions as it allows the *preceding* token to appear zero or more times. But there actually has to be something preceding it.

If you want to match a literal asterisk, then use `\*` as regular expression. Otherwise you need to specify *what* may get repeated. For example the regex `a*` matches either nothing or arbitrary many `a`s in a row.

Comment: Just to add a comment here for anyone using `Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '*text*text*'}` will fail, instead use `'text.text'`

Answer (score 21):

You appear to have a lone `"*"` in your regex. That is not correct. A `"*"` does not mean "anything" (like in a file spec), but "the previous can be repeated 0 or more times".

If you want "anything" you have to write `".*"`. The `"."` means "any single character", which will then be repeated.

**Edit**:
The same would happen if you use other quantifiers by their own: `"+"`, `"?"` or `"{n,m}"` (where n and m are numbers that specify lower and upper limit).

- "*" is identical to "{0,}",
- "+" is identical to "{1,}",
- "?" is identical to "{0,1}"

which might explain the text or the error message you get.

Comment: Any single character except, sometimes, newlines.

Answer (score 3):

thanks,

and I fixed like this

```
<%# Regex.Replace( (Model.Text ?? "").ToString(), Regex.Escape(patternText), "<b>" + patternText + "</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline)%>
```

Comment: `(Model.Text ?? "").ToString()` is actually equivalent to just `Model.Text ?? ""`, as `ToString()` on a string just returns that string.

Comment: Why do you even use Regex.Replace when String.Replace will do the job?