# Unable to match pattern from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string from which I need to fetch the ones with {{ ... }} pattern and replace them with the evaluated value.

**Note:** Some methods will be placed with in this {{abc();}}.I need to evaluate these methods and replace it with the respective outputs.

```
string abc="/*html$**{{abcd();}}**//*dhf//**{{ef();}}** ";
string pattern="*{{*}}*";
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(abc, pattern);
```

I tried using this pattern.But it is throwing the below exception.

> "{"parsing \"*{{*}}*\" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing."}"

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: See [parsing “*” - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798285/parsing-quantifier-x-y-following-nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Okay you definitely need to learn more about regex patterns since your pattern is not even compilable...

For beginners this pattern `{{[a-z]*\(\);}}` will get you `{{abc();}}`.
It's very simple since the only chars you need to escape are `(` and `)`
These are some of the special chars of a regex that split a pattern into "capturing groups" so if you want to match them you need to escape them by putting `\` infront of them. The same goes for `*` for example.

Use a site like https://regex101.com/ for testing regexes(?) and to develop my given pattern to your specific needs.

The website offers a lot of explanation on how each of the symbols in the patterns work and even shows you when your pattern string is flawed with errors.